# Why we can get such inconsistent judgments of answers?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, link-only-answers

I've come over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640506/multithreading-and-fetching-from-http-in-c) today, and found that the available answers were totally judged differently, though they had the more or less the same essence:

[image]

I've been dovn-(close) voting on both of the answers, since they show link-only solutions solely.

Why one survived over the other answer, and survived at all?

Comment: I wouldn't have deleted the second answer either. Those are not link-only answers. They both explicitly name the methods the OP should use to solve their problem. The question, on the other hand, is pretty vague.

Comment: Why did I delete an answer where the user said, "Read some book on multi-threading" But didn't delete the accepted answer with upvotes that talked about specific implementations?

Comment: See [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) Those are both answers.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot No, I'm asking about reasons for judgement! And none of them is a valid answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's fine, but according to George's answer, you flagged them both as NAA. I'm telling you that they *are* answers. Read the post I linked to.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "Link only answers" are different than "not an answer". An answer can consist solely of links and still be an answer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker _"Link only answers" are different than "not an answer"._ Yeah, I know of course. But **how do these two differ**, if not judged as being _link only_??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I address that in my answer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Did pthread quit being an implementation at some point? Is saying to use the producer-consumer or thread pool patterns not helpful?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question itself is vague.

I deleted the latter answer for a few reasons:

- It doesn't talk about any specific implementation; its utility goes only so far as someone who hasn't heard of the "Producer-Consumer" pattern.
- It tells the user to "read a book on multi-threading." That's (at best) an unhelpful statement.

The former answer (that you downvoted) had at least two upvotes prior to your downvote. It provided references to specific implementations for the OP to look at.

It wasn't a great answer, but it was far better than the one I deleted.  It was also accepted.  If I deleted that, there'd literally be no information for anyone from Google. That's not in keeping with our mantra to not delete useful content.

In the future, if you find yourself flagging multiple answers on a question, it would be preferable to vote to close the question (especially if it is the source of bad answers), or if you can't do that, flag the question for closure.

You flagged the answers as 'not an answer'. I could see the "read a book on Multithreading" to not be an answer; but the upvoted accepted answer definitely addressed the question asked. It would have been inappropriate to accept the "not an answer" flag.

Comment: _" it would be preferable to vote to close the question"_ I did so of course ...

Comment: I think you should clarify that **both flags were wrong**.  You were able to delete the unhelpful answer only because of subject-matter expertise concerning producer-consumer patterns (it wasn't really a moderation action), and not all moderators will be experts in every subject.  Flags that require a subject matter expert to process are invalid.